# Pass std::function to std::set_terminate?

Tags: c++, c++11

How would I convert an std::function into a terminate_handler, passed into the parameter of std::set_terminate? The code below is contrived but exemplifies what I am trying to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void my_terminate() {
    std::cout << "Terminating." << std::endl;
}

void set_terminate_wrapper(std::function<void()> terminate_func) {
    // Set terminate_func as the terminate function:
    std::set_terminate(/*what goes here?*/);
}

int main() {
    std::function<void()> my_func = my_terminate;
    set_terminate_wrapper(my_func);
    throw 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::function<>::target` **if applicable**...

Comment: else `static` variable might help.